# Eclipse plugin for finding declaration or references of element(s) in Javascript/Angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

In my eclipse IDE I would like to have the equivalent of the F3 (find declaration) and Ctrl-Shift-G (references) java hotkeys when working With Javascript &/or Angular code.

I realize that since JavaScript is dynamically typed it's not as easy to do this as with Java, and in fact may be nearly impossible to Guarantee absolute success in finding all references.  However, at the same time it's possible to find *nearly* all references with little more then a file search for the appropriate key word.  I'm looking for a plugin that offers at least the later, a quick search feature that will make a best-guess attempt to find declarations and references, and visualize them in a way to make it easier to navigate then a file search, even if it doesn't make a guarantee of finding all instances.

As A side note if anyone has any other must-have javascript/Angular eclipse addons they recommend and wish to mention them as well, as a comment on something, I'd love to know about whatever they recommend using; though for now my big desire is faster navigation options.

Comment: Are you totally married to Eclipse? Would you switch to another IDE if it offered these features?

Comment: @mawg not totally married no, but most of the development is in Java so I'm picking my IDE predominately by it's ability to do Java, which eclipse seems to be pretty good with; and it's a bit harder to get non-eclipse at work since they don't let us just install any code we want on our systems (even though they really should trust developers, we often know more then the IT folks we have to call to get something installed :P)

Comment: I _do _ feel your pain :-(

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started ?

Comment: Would Visual Studio Code work for you? It is excellent in other languages (I don't use Java)